# I can't find what's wrong with this SQL script

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a big script that I'm trying to execute. It's located here: https://github.com/diamondo25/mcdb-files/blob/master/mcdb-4.3-global-83/mcdb-4.3-global-83.sql.gz

However, I'm receviing the following errors: [image]

I really tried everything but failed. I know it's a big script but unfortunately I have no other place than StackOverflow to ask for help. BTW I'm using MariaDB and MySQL query browser to execute it.

Here's the queries before line 28:

```
/*Data for the table `block_chat_reason_data` */

insert  into `block_chat_reason_data`(`id`,`reason`,`message`) values (1,'Foul Language','Foul language/Harrassment'),(2,'Advertising','Advertising websites'),(3,'Hack','Fake GM'),(4,'Account Trading','Trading or selling account'),(5,'Trading','Do not report fame scams and trade scams. '),(6,'Penalty Alert','The reporter\'s conversation is also subject to penalties.');

/*Table structure for table `block_reason_data` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `block_reason_data`;

CREATE TABLE `block_reason_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `block_type` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `message` varchar(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Comment: update you question and add the text for the sql command please and the code taht preced  the command  too

Comment: You want us to debug a script over 2000 lines long?

Comment: @Mihai No, the error states the lines where the issues are - but I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: IN general when you get a error message in mysql the error is exactly before that message.So in the first error,before  DROP TABLE... there is an error,probably the previous statement is not ended with ;.IF you cant find it edit you question with the statements BEFORE the errors

Comment: @Mihai I added the statement BEFORE the first error. Can you point out what's wrong with it ?Then I can get a general ide about the others.

Comment: @Mihai I believe the issue is with "The reporter\'s", I'm using MariaDB so it might not recognize that escape sequence? Anyways I changed it and now other errors popped up in new places. Am I in the right direction?

Comment: But we need the part after that. Where you create the new table. Tabel block_reason_data

Comment: Are you using phpmyadmin?If so change it to some other client like heidisql,phpmyadmin tends to stumble often.

Comment: @Mihai Nope, jsut MariaDB

Comment: I mean the interface you are using to run that script,mariadb is the database.Are you running it from the command line?

Comment: in error message first line it has `server version for the right syntax` for `drop` table. your query for droping table and creating works in phpmyadmin.

Comment: can you also add table structure(query for) `block_chat_reason_data` table.

Comment: Is the size of the fields in `block_chat_reason_data` big enough for what the INSERT tries to put in them?

Answer (score -1):

You are not escaping comma, try

```
insert  into `block_chat_reason_data`(`id`,`reason`,`message`) values (1,'Foul Language','Foul language/Harrassment'),(2,'Advertising','Advertising websites'),(3,'Hack','Fake GM'),(4,'Account Trading','Trading or selling account'),(5,'Trading','Do not report fame scams and trade scams. '),(6,'Penalty Alert','The reporter\''s conversation is also subject to penalties.');
```

Answer (score -1):

Last comma is the problem on line 5.

So use this:

```
CREATE TABLE `block_reason_data`(
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `block_type` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `message` varchar(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Comment: You almost certainly need a comma between `DEFAULT ''` and `PRIMARY KEY (id)`.